# Spring & JNDI: locate resource platform independent

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, weblogic, jndi

I'm trying to load in a property file provided by JNDI which should be platform independent. I know I can do it in the following ways, dependent on the platform:

**For Weblogic:**

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
InitialContext context = new InitialContext(properties);
context.lookup(propertiesLocation);
```

**For Tomcat:**

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) context.lookup("java:comp/env");
final Object lookup = envCtx.lookup(propertiesLocation);
```

The core problem is that in `Tomcat` the prefix `java:comp/env/` is needed. Since `Spring` is able to load all this platform independently, I tried looking into the possibilities of `Spring` loading my `JNDI` resources.

I found out I can use the `JndiTemplate` of Spring in the following way:

```
JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
Object lookup = jndiTemplate.lookup(propertiesLocation);
```

This is still platform dependent however, needing to use `java:comp/env` as a prefix during the lookup on tomcat. Looking further on `StackOverflow` and in the `Spring` javadocs, I found the class `JndiLocatorSupport`, which has the following:

> JNDI names may or may not include the "java:comp/env/" prefix expected by J2EE applications when accessing a locally mapped (ENC - Environmental Naming Context) resource. If it doesn't, the "java:comp/env/" prefix will be prepended if the "resourceRef" property is true (the default is false) and no other scheme (e.g. "java:") is given.

So I created a `JndiObjectFactoryBean` which extends `JndiLocatorSupport`, enabled `setResourceRef` but it doesn't seem to append the prefix.

**Core problem:**
When using the following code:

```
JndiObjectFactoryBean factoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
factoryBean.setResourceRef(true);
Object lookup = factoryBean.getJndiTemplate().lookup(propertiesLocation);
```

I'd expect it to have the same effect as:

```
JndiObjectFactoryBean factoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
Object lookup = factoryBean.getJndiTemplate().lookup("java:comp/env/" + propertiesLocation);
```

But it doesn't. It seems to have no effect at all. But if I look through the source code, it does go like this:
`JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookup()` -> `JndiObjectLocator.lookup()` -> `JndiLocatorSupport.lookup()`, which [does call](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.collector/1.3.5/org/springframework/jndi/JndiLocatorSupport.java#JndiLocatorSupport.lookup%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Class%29) the right methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JndiObjectFactoryBean factoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
factoryBean.setResourceRef(true);
Object lookup = factoryBean.getJndiTemplate().lookup(propertiesLocation);
```

and

```
JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
Object lookup = jndiTemplate.lookup(propertiesLocation);
```

Are the same with regards to the lookup. The first is only a very complex way to obtain a `JndiTemplate`. All the settings you do are for the `JndiObjectFactoryBean` NOT for the internal `JndiTemplate`. Basically your whole approach doesn't add anything.

Instead use a [`JndiLocatorDelegate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiLocatorDelegate.html) and let that do the lookup (don't try to get the `JndiTemplate`!).

```
JndiLocatorDelegate jndi = JndiLocatorDelegate.createDefaultResourceRefLocator();
Object lookup = jndi.lookup(propertiesLocation);
```

This will by default do a lookup in `java:comp/env` and if not found do a fallback to a plain `propertiesLocation` (what you passed in).